# How can I use wget to download files through html links?

Tags: linux, wget, html

I am trying to use wget to download files from a database through a website. The provider is now only providing web access to what was previously an ftp server that I could easily use wget to download any files I wanted.

I am having trouble understanding how to do this with wget; I am attempting to recursively download these files from various directories at level 3 with the command

```
wget -nd -nc -nH -r -np -A .tar.gz "https://ftp.website.org/pub/current/" --spider -l3 -e robots=off
```

I tried adding options such as --convert-links etc but all I obtain is index.html.tmp. If someone has experience with this I would appreciate any assistance! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can like this

```
wget -r -l3 -np -nc -nH -A.tar.gz "https://ftp.website.org/pub/current/" -P /home/user/folder/
```

You may also include the option `--no-check-certificate` if the website you're trying to download from has SSL certificate issues, which will allow you to bypass the SSL certificate check.

Comment: Hi, yes, I tried that too but did not work. I emailed the provider but they did not answer at least not yet.